# not displaying the last object that i am entering in the createstudent function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

whatever i am sending through create student function i am getting that in mongodb. But when i try to display the same in the node i am not getting the last updated name and age. But i when i try to run the server again i am getting the last name and age also.now what should i do to get at the first time itself??

this is server code

```
import config from './config';
import express from 'express';
const server= express();

import mongodbInterface from'./mongodbInterface';
server.set('view engine','ejs');
server.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('index',{
    content:'...'
  })
});
console.log(typeof mongodbInterface.createStudent);
mongodbInterface.createStudent("abhi",99);

server.use(express.static('public'));
server.listen(config.port,()=>{
  console.info('express listening on port',config.port);
});
```

this is my mongodb code

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var db= mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/student');

mongoose.connect('connected',function(){
    console.log("database connected successfully")
});

var userSchema=new Schema({
Name:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
Age:{type:Number,required:true}
},{collection :'studentcollection'});

   var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
function createStudent(name,age){
     var list=new User({
       Name:name,
       Age: age
     });

list.save(function() {

    User.find({}, function(err, studentcollection) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(studentcollection);
        console.log("successful")
    });
});
}
exports.createStudent = createStudent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like this

```
return list.save().then(function() {

    return User.find({});
}).then(function(UsersData){
    console.log(UsersData);

    return UsersData;
});
```

Comment: i have followed your code but now its not dispaying anything.

Answer (score 0):

**try like this way,this will return updated record** :

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/student');

var userSchema = new Schema({
    Name:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
    Age:{type:Number,required:true}
  },{collection :'studentcollection'});

var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);


function createStudent(name,age,done){
     var list = new User({
       Name:name,
       Age: age
     });
    list.save(function(err,user) {



User.find({},{},{}, function(err, studentcollection) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(studentcollection);
    console.log("successful")
});
      //if(err) return done(error,null);
      //return done(null,user)
      console.log(user)
    });
  });

exports.createStudent = createStudent;


**And One most important thing is : If you want to create any Crud like createStudent  then create separate file for that.**
```

Comment: I don''t want to just display last added name and age. i want to display all the data including last added data.